# EKS created a default Role and Policies without "eks:createCluster" avoiding my role created on my own aws CDK NodeJS TypeScript

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

i got the next error bellow:
`

```
cdkDeploystack1 | 43/71 | 4:23:22 p. m. | CREATE_FAILED        | Custom::AWSCDK-EKS-Cluster            | cdkDeploy--dev--ClusterEKS/cdkDeploy--dev--ClusterEKS/Resource/Resource/Default (cdkDeploydevClusterEKS37F9DAF6) Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: User: arn:aws:sts::account_id:assumed-role/cdkDeploystack1-cdkDeploydevClusterEKSCreationRoleE-MwTJR5LYTdg8/AWSCDK.EKSCluster.Create.1c33a711-005a-46b4-8ed3-2c7f84f0d368 is not authorized to perform: eks:CreateCluster on resource: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:account_id:cluster/*
```

these are dependencies:

```
"@aws-cdk/lambda-layer-kubectl-v27": "^2.1.0",
"aws-cdk-lib": "2.93.0",
"constructs": "^10.0.0",
"source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
```

i hid my account_id but it's appears correctly

But i've been stuck for several days with the same error and i tried many things but nothing worked.

[these are the prev messages process before the error message that recently i saw it (eks created default role and policies therefore this is the problem, i think so:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYRTJ.jpg)

this is my code on the first version:

```
      const eksPolicy = new iam.PolicyDocument({
          statements: [
            new iam.PolicyStatement({
              effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
              actions: ['eks:*', 'sts:*'],
              resources: ['*', "arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:id:cluster/*"], // Adjust resource ARN as needed
            }),
          ],
        });
      const eksRole = new iam.Role(this, 'EksClusterRole', {
          assumedBy: new iam.AccountRootPrincipal(), // Assumed by the root account for simplicity
        });

      eksRole.attachInlinePolicy(new iam.Policy(this, 'EksCreateClusterPolicy', {
          document: eksPolicy,
        }));
        
      new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'EksClusterRoleArn', {
          value: eksRole.roleArn,
        });

        this.clusterKmsKey = new Key(
        this, 
        `ekskmskey`, 
        {
        enableKeyRotation: true,
        alias: cdk.Fn.join('', ['alias/', 'eks/', `ekskmskey`]),
      }); 
      
      this.cluster = new eks.Cluster(this, `${getString(projectProps, 'project_name')}/${getString(projectProps, 'environment')}/ClusterEKS`, {
        version: eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_27,
        defaultCapacity: 3,  // we want to manage capacity our selves
        endpointAccess: eks.EndpointAccess.PUBLIC_AND_PRIVATE,
        vpc: vpc.vpc,
        role: eksRole,
        mastersRole: eksRole,
        secretsEncryptionKey: this.clusterKmsKey,
        securityGroup,
        clusterName: `${getString(projectProps, 'project_name')}/${getString(projectProps, 'environment')}/ClusterEKS`,
        placeClusterHandlerInVpc: true,
        kubectlLayer: new KubectlV27Layer(this, 'kubectl'),
        vpcSubnets: [vpc.vpc.selectSubnets({
          subnets: vpc.subn,
          onePerAz: true,
        })],
      });
      this.cluster.awsAuth.addRoleMapping(eksRole, { groups: [ 'system:masters' ]});

      this.cluster.awsAuth.addMastersRole(eksRole);

      this.cluster.addNodegroupCapacity("managed-node", {
        instanceTypes: [ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO)],
        minSize: 1,
        maxSize: 2,
        nodeRole: eksRole
      });

      
      this.asg = this.cluster.addAutoScalingGroupCapacity(
        `${getString(projectProps, 'project_name')}/${getString(projectProps, 'environment')}/AutoScalingGroupEKS`, 
        {
        keyName: 'keypemToConnect',
        instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
        machineImageType: eks.MachineImageType.BOTTLEROCKET,
        autoScalingGroupName: `${getString(projectProps, 'project_name')}/${getString(projectProps, 'environment')}/AutoScalingGroupEKS`,
        allowAllOutbound: false,
        healthCheck: autoscaling.HealthCheck.ec2(),
        minCapacity: 2,
        maxCapacity: 4,
        vpcSubnets: vpc.vpc.selectSubnets({
          subnets: vpc.subn,
          onePerAz: true,
        }),
      })
      console.log('autoScalling pass');

      this.asg.connections.allowTo(this.cluster, ec2.Port.tcp(443), 'Allow between BastionHost and EKS ');
     
      this.asg.userData.addCommands(
        `VERSION=$(aws --region ${projectProps.region} eks describe-cluster --name ${this.cluster.clusterName} --query 'cluster.version' --output text)`,
        'echo \'K8s version is $VERSION\'',
        'curl -LO https://dl.k8s.io/release/v$VERSION.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl',
        'install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /bin/kubectl',
      );
         
      this.awsauth = new eks.AwsAuth(this, 'EKS_AWSAUTH', {
        cluster: this.cluster,
      });
```

how can you see i used to create eks cluster a own role that i creating and the name is not equal to the role error and of course my own role has eks:* (ell permissions eks).. This cant be posible...

i decided that this behavior could be for async/sync idk... and therefore i created my own role using the aws console and this role i converted like a administrator:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i replaced the creation role on the first version on my code for this:

```
       const eksRole: iam.IRole = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(
                                  this, 
                                  'rolARN', 
                                  getString(projectProps,'role_arn_admin')
                                  )
```

pd: role_arn_admin is a element i stored within yaml file envs (contains the role arn that i created on the aws console)

and nothing both mathods...  the same error apears when i tried to cdk deploy again... (i removed cdk.out and i executed cdk boostrap before deploy again)

my user aws cdk has the "eks:*" permissions too, and the problem told "role is not authorized to perform eks:createCluster"..  in this situation i just think that the reason is probably a something error eks with the any vinculation role method....  avoiding my role created on my own using aws console or by code execution... idk... Please, help me i dont know what to do...

this is the IAN Statements changes before execution the process deploy:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTlEb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9kGu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukTqh.jpg)

```
cdkDeploy--dev--ClusterEKS/cdkDeploy--dev--ClusterEKS/Resource/Resource/Default (cdkDeploydevClusterEKS37F9DAF6) Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: User: arn:aws:sts::account_id:assumed-role/cdkDeploystack1-cdkDeploydevClusterEKSCreationRoleE-0Lz20EWA7OHG/AWSCDK.EKSCluster.Create.6fad2316-6b58-476a-a5f3-a95877a010ab is not authorized to perform: eks:CreateCluster on resource: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:account_id:cluster/*

Logs: /aws/lambda/cdkDeploystack1-awscdkawsek-OnEventHandler42BEBAE0-Xun2vBY9ZSK4

    at throwDefaultError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:8:22)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:18:39
    at de_CreateClusterCommandError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-eks/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_restJson1.js:1238:20)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24
    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/awsAuthMiddleware.js:30:20
    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46
    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26
    at async ClusterResourceHandler.onCreate (/var/task/cluster.js:1:1019) (RequestId: 6fad2316-6b58-476a-a5f3-a95877a010ab)
```

someone help me to fix my error or a new guid the creation eks